# Class inheritance NameError:

Tags: python

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class FirstClass():
   def setdata(self,value):
       self.data=value
   def getname(self,name):
       self.data=name
   def display(self):
       print self.data

x = FirstClass( )
y = FirstClass( )

x.setdata("King Arthur")
x.getname("dnj")
x.display()

class SecondClass(FirstClass):
   def display(self):
      print 'Current value = "%s"' % self.data

z = SecondClass()
z.setdata(42)
z.display()

class ThirdClass(FirstClass):
   def display(self):
      print 'Her name is = "%s"' % self.data

p = ThirdClass()
p.getname(dunja)
p.display()
```

When I run it,I got this:

```
dnj
Current value = "42"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pr54.py", line 31, in <module>
    p.getname(dunja)
NameError: name 'dunja' is not defined
```

Should I create other display function or ...? I do not understand why it is not working,becuse the hierarchy is the same.

Comment: Why does your ``getname`` method set a member? That's very misleading.

Comment: You have to pass a String there. Without Quotes python interprets this as a variable, which you haven't initialized yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dunja` is treated as a variable. To treat it as a string put it as

```
p = ThirdClass()
p.getname("dunja")
p.display()
```